# How to add a function into utils module on titanic data set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run the following code. I am having an error saying `AttributeError: module 'python_utils' has no attribute 'clean_data'`, but I know know how to fix it.

```
import python_utils
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

def clean_data(data):
    data["Fare"]=data["Fare"].fillna(data["Fare"].dropna().median())
    data["Age"]=data["Age"].fillna(data["age"].dropna().median())

    data.loc[data["Sex"]=="male", "Sex"]=0
    data.loc[data["Sex"]=="female", "Sex"]=1

    data["Embarked"]=data["Embarked"].fillna("S")
    data.loc[data["Embarked"]=="S",Embarked]=0
    data.loc[data["Embarked"]=="C",Embarked]=1
    data.loc[data["Embarked"]=="Q",Embarked]=2

train=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
python_utils.clean_data(train)
target=train["Survived"].values
features=train[["Pclass","Age","Sex","SibSp","Parch"]].values
classifier=linear_model.logisticRegression()
classifier=classifier.fit(features,target)
print(classifier_.score(features,target))
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to add that function to `python_utils`?  Why can't you just call whatever implementation you'd add for that function as your own function instead of calling it as an attribute of `dist_utils`? - What an error like this usually means is that you're using the wrong version of the module in question.

Comment: The only function I can find mentioned on the web with a similar signature to the one you want to add is `python.utils.pca_normalize_dataset`.  Could it be that it is this function that you want to call?

Comment: I am very beginner currently I was following an online exercise. Instructor in the video started with this block of code 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model 
import utils
and then runs the following 
utils.clean_data(train)
target=train["Survived"].values
features=train[["Pclass","Age","Sex","SibSp","Parch"]].values
classifier=linear_model.LogisticRegression()
classifier=classifier.fit(features,target)
print(classifier_.score(features,target)) 
however my version gives an error. I searched on the web and to get the utils module I used import python_utils.

Comment: Gotcha.  As a beginner then, you shouldn't be looking for a way to add that one function call to the existing module.  If your instructor is using that call and you don't have it, then you are almost definitely using a different version of the module.  You should never have to add functions to an external module.  I would ask your instructor about this.